# Insert data / update if already exists

Tags: php, mysql

This code works. I can't figure out how to insert data into db If user pressed "SAVE" button for the first time or update data.

**The php side**

```
<?php
require '../../core/includes/common.php';

$name=filter($_POST['name'], $db);
$title=filter($_POST['title'], $db);
$parentcheck=filter($_POST['parentcheck'],$db);
if(isset ($_POST['parent'])) $parent=filter($_POST['parent'],$db);
else $parent=$parentcheck;  
$menu=filter($_POST['menu'], $db);
$content = $db->escape_string($_POST['content']);

$result=$db->query("INSERT INTO menu (parent, name, showinmenu) VALUES ('$parent', '$name', '$menu')") or die($db->error);
$new_id = $db->insert_id;
$result2=$db->query("INSERT INTO pages (id, title, content) VALUES ('$new_id', '$title', '$content')") or die($db->error);  

if ($new_id>0){  
echo "{";  
echo '"msg": "success" ';
echo "}";  
}else{ 
echo "{"; 
echo
'"err": "error"';  
echo "}";  
}

?>
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @jmlsteeke i found the way

Place this piece of code in html part

```
<?php
$result=$db->query("INSERT INTO menu (parent, name, showinmenu) VALUES ('555', 'new', '0')") or die($db->error);
$new_id = $db->insert_id;
$result2=$db->query("INSERT INTO pages (id, title, content) VALUES ('$new_id', 'new', 'new')") or die($db->error);  

?>
```

And added following code into form

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$new_id?>"/>
```

In serverside script used

```
$result=$db->query("UPDATE pages AS p, menu AS m SET m.parent='$parent', m.name='$name', m.showinmenu='$menu', p.id='$id', p.title='$title', p.content='$content' WHERE m.id='$id' AND p.id=m.id") or die($db->error);
```

Thank you @jmlsteeke

Comment: That's not quite what I meant, but I don't know how to explain it any better without seeing/editing the entirety of your code.  Also it's well past time for me to go to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way would be to store the id as a hidden field when you are editing the page.  This way when the user submits the page, if there is an id present, you issue the UPDATE commands, and if there isn't one present, you know it's a new page, and issue the INSERT commands.

If you need me to be more thorough let me know.

Edit: Being More Thorough

I'll make a simple, complete, example of what I mean.

Form.php pseudo code

```
//set default values for fields
//print form tag
if (isset($'id',$_GET)) {
    //fetch data from database
    //print hidden id field
    //override default values for fields
}
//print rest of fields using default values (possibly overridden)
```

DoForm.php pseudo code

```
//Sanitize user input
if (isset('id',$_POST)) {
    //UPDATE database with user input
} else {
    //INSERT new rows into table with user input
}
```

Let's say you have a php file called Form.php which is responsible for displaying the form, and another php script called DoForm.php which is responsible for handling the form.

If a user visits Form.php with no ID specified (http://example.com/Form.php) then it will display the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="DoForm.php">
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="text" name="title" value="" />
... other stuff ...
</form>
```

The user will add some information, click on the submit button and DoForm will get the following POST variables:

```
"name"  => "NewPageName"
"title" => "My First Webpag" [intetional typo, see later]
... other stuff ...
```

DoForm will check to see if `$_POST['id']` exists.  Since it doesn't DoForm issues the INSERT commands to add a new page.

Later on, the user realises the made a typo, and goes to fix it.  The user clicks on the "Edit Page" control for "NewPageName" which will be `http://example.com/Form.php?id=1`

Form.php see's that id is set, so the form it prints out is as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="DoForm.php">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"
<input type="text" name="name" value="NewPageName" />
<input type="text" name="title" value="My First Webpag" />
... other stuff ...
</form>
```

The user fixes their type, changing Webpag to Webpage, and hits submit.  DoForm gets the following Post variables

```
"id"    => 1
"name"  => "NewPageName"
"title" => "My First Webpage"
... other stuff ...
```

DoForm sees that id is set, and so uses UPDATE instead of INSERT.

Any more clear?

Comment: To be clear it's content management system. Let's say user adds new page. First time when user pushes "Save" button it inserts content with new id. My html side send data via ajax. For ex. user continues page editing and pushes second time "Save". How to update existing field? Please edit code if it's possible

Comment: The HTML for adding a page and for editing a page will have to be slightly different.  When you edit a page you need to add a hidden input field that contains the page ID <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<page.id>" />.  Then when they click the save button, the page id will be transmitted along with the page data.  Your PHP will check to see if id was submitted, much like you check for parentcheck, and if it was submitted then do an update using that id.  If it wasn't then do an insert, exactly like you are now.

Comment: I can't edit the code because this it requires a change to code that you haven't included.

Comment: Listen, db table generates my id, it's autoincremented value. How to retrieve id if it doesn't exist at all?

Comment: Use case 1:  New Page.  User clicks on "New Page", your script generates an HTML form that doesn't contain the hidden id element.  User submits that form, a new page is created using INSERT commands.

Comment: Use Case 2:  Edit Page.  User clicks on Edit Page.  your script generates an HTML form with the hidden id element.  At this point, since you are editing an existing page, the id DOES exist in the database.  You add the hidden element to the form, as well as pre-filling the existing data into the text boxes and whatnot.  User clicks submit.  Your PHP script notices there is and id specified, uses it, in conjunction with the other data, to UPDATE the database.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has an [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) feature that will let you try to insert a row, or fall back to an update if it discovers a duplicate key (i.e. the row already exists).

Comment: If he has a key other than id then this would be the way to go for sure, but based on the context I don't think this will work because it's entirely possible that none of the other data needs to be unique.  Looking at it the only possibility I can see for there being a unique key would be parent+name, but it's entirely feasible that they would want to have multiple children with the same names (maybe not the best practice, but not the craziest either).

Comment: To be clear it's content management system. Let's say user adds new page. First time when user pushes "Save" button it inserts content with new id. My html side send data via ajax. For ex. user continues page editing and pushes second time "Save". How to update existing field? Please edit code if it's possible